# What is the reason of Activity Notification Sends 0

Tags: urbanairship.com

Can anyone tell me please, what is reason behind Notification Sends Value 0?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why a particular push could have 0 Notification Sends.

I would make a Forum Post or submit a support ticket on the [Urban Airship Support Site](http://support.urbanairship.com) with some more information, such as your app key. The support agents there can then help troubleshoot your specific issue.